# Cannot Insert into sqlite

Tags: java, sql, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm still learning Ionic and programming in general. I followed a link on the internet and I was able to create the white and read the necessary data, but I am not able to insert data in the created table. Can anyone help me with this?

I follow this tutorial: [ionic-sqlite](https://github.com/taaa22/Ionic-Sqlite)

My code:

```
getRegiao() {                  // Regiões // 
return new Promise<Regiao[]>((resolve, reject) => {
  let sql = "SELECT NOM_REGIAO, ID " +
    "FROM TB_REGIAO  "


  this.executeQuery(sql).then(data => {
    let regioes = [];
    if (data != undefined)
      data.forEach(function (row) {
        let regiao: Regiao = { nom_regiao: row[0], id: row[1] }
        regioes.push(regiao);
      });
    resolve(regioes);

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});

}

 addUser() {

let sql = "INSERT INTO TB_USUARIO (EMAIL) VALUES ('BLITCRANK@HOTMAIL.COM')";
// let sql = "SELECT EMAIL FROM TB_USUARIO";
this.executeQuery(sql);
}

executeQuery(sql: string) {
let db: any;
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', this.dbName, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  xhr.onload = (e) => {
    let uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
    db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
    let contents = db.exec(sql);
    console.log(contents);
    if (contents.length > 0)
      resolve(contents[0].values);
    else 
      resolve("query executada sem retorno")
  };
  xhr.send();

});
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you share it?

Comment: Hello, I'm not getting error, but just not adding to the database.

Comment: Unfortunately in the link that I put in the description of the problem, I did not find anything on how to insert .. I believe it is with "ExecuteQuery"

Answer (score 0):

Please use this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/) , this is the plugin that I am using.

Take note in using execute sql like this `db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {})`

But rather use this `db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', [])`

I dont know why instead of using object '{}' they replace it as array '[]' I think they forgot to update the documentaion

Comment: but my data is in sql.js using its solution I can insert into the table that I created with sql.js?